# Allow any password for a specific mysql user

Tags: mysql, database

I have an old application from a friend that is dependent on a table in a MySQL database. The application makes calls directly to the database - Sends login request and subsequent retrieval activities.

The password is hard-coded into the application and he forgot what it is. However, we do have the table structure and is able to allow the database connection to connect if we used *skip-grant-tables* to bypass the authentication.

Is there a way to only allow a specific user to have such privilege (logging in with any password with a specific username) and not affect the remaining users?

P.s: I understand that this is not the ideal way to create an application and APIs should be used instead. However, the application is useful but not worth to redevelop.

Comment: SQL Server is not MySQL. Please don't tag irrelevant.

Comment: Seems like there's probably a pretty good chance the password is stored as a plain string somewhere in the application, and could be found with appropriate tools.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Sorry for the late response. The app is compiled to an .exe and we lost the source code.

Comment: Okay, but even .exes have plain strings in them. The text of any dialogs, for example. And most likely the password is in there somewhere. There are [many tools](https://superuser.com/questions/124081/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-strings-command) that can extract that information for you. You'd be able to quickly discard most of the output as being obviously something from the program's UI. Possible that the password would be near the user name. No guarantee that you'd find it this way, obviously, but it seems worth a try.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I tried using the strings program from the tools you suggested by no luck. Do you happen to know other possible methods?

Comment: There are things called "decompilers", which will turn a `.exe` back into some kind of source code, but I have never worked with such a thing, so I can't make any predictions of how much work it might take or what the likelihood of success would be.